# Dart / Flutter The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make the a Button in flutter reusable as it is pretty much the same except for the Color of the Button. As far as I understand from a number search results, the datatype for *colors* is `Color`. But when I do the following it gives me an error saying `The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.`

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color buttonColor;
  final Color textColor;

  const CustomButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.buttonColor,
    required this.textColor,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

And I mentioned it like the following:

```
style: TextStyle(
   fontSize: 16,
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   color: Color(textColor)),
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `color` in the `TextStyle` accepts a value of type `Color` which is a dart object, not the integer value of the color code.

So you can keep `textColor` with type `Color` and use it like the following:

```
style: TextStyle(
    ...
    color: textColor // textColor is a variable of type Color
    ...
),
```

Or change the type of the `textColor` variable to be `int` containing the value (Color Code) of the color, example: `0xFFFF0000`, and then use it like the following:

```
style: TextStyle(
    ...
    color: Color(textColor) // textColor is a variable of type int containing the color code
    ...
),
```

Comment: Okay, so I just have to put Color(0xFFFFF000) or any other color like this way then. Now I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're always welcome ❤️